# Good practice to fetch detail api data in react-redux app

Tags: api, reactjs, redux

Whats the best practice to fetch details data in react app when you are dealing with multiple master details view?

For an example if you have 
- /rest/departments api which returns list of departments
- /rest/departments/:departmentId/employees api to return all employees within department.

To fetch all departments i use:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchDepartments());
}
```

but then ill need a logic to fetch all employees per department. Would be a great idea to call employee action creator for each department in department reducer logic?

Dispatching employees actions in render method does not look like a good idea to me.

Comment: the department list and detail can be rendered with two different routes ?

Comment: You could store some sort of active department in your store, in order to dynamically create the new request, kind of `{activeDepartment:"sales"}`. Then use that in a general employees reducer: `this.props.getEmployees(this.props.activeDepartment)`. That's what I'd try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it is a bad idea to call an employee action creator inside the department reducer, as reducers should be pure functions; you should do it in your fetchDepartments action creator.

Anyway, if you need to get all the employees for every department (not just the selected one), it is not ideal to make many API calls: if possible, I would ask to the backend developers to have an endpoint that returns the array of departments and, for each department, an embedded array of employees, if the numbers aren't too big of course...

Answer (score 1):

Big old "It depends"

This is something that in the end, you will need to pick a way and see how it works out with your specific data and user needs.  This somewhat deals with network issues as well, such as latency.  In a very nicely networked environment, such as a top-3 insurance company I was a net admin for, you can achieve super low latency network calls.  In such a case, multiple network requests would be significantly different than a homeowner internet based environment could be.  Even then, you have to consider a wide range of possibilities.  And you ALWAYS need to consider your end goals.

(Not to get too down in the technical aspects, but latency can fairly accurately be defined as "the time you are waiting for a network request to actually start sending data".  A classic example of where this can be important is online first person shooter gaming.  You click shoot, and the data is not transmitted as fast as you would like since the network is waiting to send the data, then you die.  A classic example where bandwidth is more useful than latency is downloading or uploading large files.  If you have to wait a second or two for the actual data to move, but when it moves you can download a GB in seconds, then oh well, I'll take it.)

Currently, I have our website making multiple calls to load dynamic menus and dynamic content.  It is very small data.  It is done in three separate calls.  On the internet.  It's "ok", but I would not say that it is "good".  Since users are waiting for all of it to even start, I might as well throw it all in a single network call.  Also, in case two calls go ok, then the third chokes a bit, the user may start to navigate, then more menus pop in and it is not ideal.  This is why regardless, you have to think about your specific needs, and what range of possible use cases may likely apply.  (I am currently re-writing the entire site anyways)

As a previous (in my opinion "good") answer stated, it probably makes sense to have the whole data set shot to you in one gulp.  It appears to me this is an internal, or at least commercial app, with decent network and much more importantly, no risk of losing customers because your stuff did not load super fast.

That said, if things do not work out well with that, especially if you are talking large data sets, then consider a lazy loading architecture.  For example, your user cannot get to an employee until they see the departments.  So it may be ok, depending on your network and large data size, to load departments, and then after it returns initiate an asynchronous load of the employee data.  The employee data is now being loaded while your user browses the department names.

A huge question you may want to clarify is whether or not any employee list data is rendered WITH the departments.  In one of my cases, I have a work order system that I load after login, but lazy, and when it is loaded it throws a badge on the Work Order menu to show how many are outstanding.  Since I do not have a lot of orders, it is basically a one second wait.  No biggie.  It is not like the user has to wait for it to load to begin work.  If you wanted a badge per department, then it may get weird.  You could, if you load by department, have multiple badges popping in randomly.  In this case, it may cause user confusion, and it probably a good choice to load it in one large chunk.  If the user has to wait anyways, it may produce one less call with a user asking "is it ok that it is doing this?".  Especially with software for the workplace, it is more acceptable to have to wait for an initial load at the beginning of the work day.

To be clear, with all of these complications to consider, it is extremely important that you develop with as good of software coding practices as you are able.  This way, you can code one solution, and if it does not meet your performance or user needs, it is not a nightmare to make a change.  In a general case with small data, I would just load it in one big gulp to start, and if there are problems with load times complicate it from there.  Complicating code from the beginning for no clearly needed reason is a good way to clutter your code up to the point of making it completely unwieldy to maintain.

On a third note, if you are dealing with enterprise size data sets, that is a whole different thing.  Then you have to deal with pagination, and yes it gets a bit more complicated.

Regards,

DB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `fetchDepartments` does exactly but I'd ensure the actual `fetch` request is executed from a Redux middleware. By doing it from middleware, you can fingerprint / cache / debounce all your requests and make a single one across the app no matter how many components request the thing.

In general, middleware is the best place to handle asynchronous side effects.